# NSFetchedResultsController Delegate is removing and object from the results controller when I select a tableview row

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Core Data Master-Detail Application.

When my `tableView` loads it presents a view with `UIButtons` to select what category of items you want to view. The `IBAction` for the buttons takes that category and creates a `NSFetchedResultsController` with a `NSPredicate` based on that category. The only difference between the buttons is, 2 of the 8 buttons sets the `predicate` to grab all the objects based on a `BOOL`/`NSNumber` value that is set as a property on the object. The other 6 buttons grab all the objects based on their "category" which again is a `NSString` property set on the object

**My Issue:**

When I select any of the buttons that grab the objects by the category (`NSString`) everything works fine. It loads the tableview with all the correct objects I select a row the delegate method `-controller didChangeObject` is called with the type `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` I pass in object to the `DetailViewController` and all is well.

When I select any of the buttons that grab the objects by the `BOOL` value everything appears to work fine. The tableview loads all the correct objects and displays properly. **However,** when I select a row the delegate method `-controller didChangeObject` is called with the type `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete` and my object is removed from the tableview. The `DetailViewController` is pushed on to the stack and displays all the information correctly.

I don't know why it is removing my object from the fetched results, it makes no sense to me. Because there is nothing different that I am doing besides the fetch by `BOOL` property rather than the `NSString` property.

Also; when I select a row I change a property value on the object in the `-tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. The property I change is just a BOOL value to track if the item has been viewed or not yet. When I remove this line of code that changes this property value everything works fine. I don't understand why this line of code doesn't effect the other categories, only the category that grabs from the `BOOL` property.

**CODE:** 
**IBAction for Categories buttons**

```
-(IBAction)goToPage:(id)sender {

BOOL wishList = NO;
    BOOL cellar = NO;

    if ((UIButton*)sender == americanButton) {
        selectedCategory = @"american";
        selectedSubCategory = nil;
        wishList = NO;
        cellar = NO;
    } else if ((UIButton*)sender == canadianButton) {
        selectedCategory = @"canadian";
        selectedSubCategory = nil;
        wishList = NO;
        cellar = NO;
    } else if ((UIButton*)sender == irishButton) {
        selectedCategory = @"irish";
        selectedSubCategory = nil;
        wishList = NO;
        cellar = NO;
    } else if ((UIButton*)sender == japaneseButton) {
        selectedCategory = @"japanese";
        selectedSubCategory = nil;
        wishList = NO;
        cellar = NO;
    } else if ((UIButton*)sender == scottishButton) {
        selectedCategory = @"scotch";
        selectedSubCategory = nil;
        wishList = NO;
        cellar = NO;
    } else if ((UIButton*)sender == verticalsButton) {
        selectedCategory = @"verticals";
        selectedSubCategory = nil;
        wishList = NO;
        cellar = NO;
    } else if ((UIButton*)sender == otherButton) {
        selectedCategory = @"other";
        selectedSubCategory = nil;
        wishList = NO;
        cellar = NO;
    } else if ((UIButton*)sender == wishListButton) {
        selectedSubCategory = @"wishlist";
        selectedCategory = nil;
        wishList = YES;
        cellar = NO;
    } else if ((UIButton*)sender == cellarButton) {
        selectedSubCategory = @"cellar";
        selectedCategory = nil;
        wishList = NO;
        cellar = YES;
    }

     if (wishList == YES) {
        [self fetchMyWhiskiesFromCategory:@"1" andResetFetchResultsController:YES withAttribute:@"wishlist"];
    } else if (cellar == YES) {
        [self fetchMyWhiskiesFromCategory:@"1" andResetFetchResultsController:YES withAttribute:@"mycellar"];
    } else {
        [self fetchMyWhiskiesFromCategory:selectedCategory andResetFetchResultsController:YES withAttribute:@"category"];
    }
}

- (void)fetchMyWhiskiesFromCategory:(NSString *)category andResetFetchResultsController:(BOOL)reset withAttribute:(NSString *)attribute
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchedResultsController *resultsController = [self fetchedResultsControllerWithCategory:category andResetFetchResultsController:reset withAttribute:attribute];

    if (![resultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error! %@", error);
    }
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsControllerWithCategory:(NSString *)category andResetFetchResultsController:(BOOL)reset withAttribute:(NSString *)attribute
{
    if (reset == YES) {
        // If asking for new results controller with new category
        NSLog(@"Reset results");
        self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
        _fetchedResultsController = nil;
    }

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        //NSLog(@"returned Old Controller");
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

    //Entity
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Whisky" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];



    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@",attribute, category];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    //Sort all entities by name property (whisky name)
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name"ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


    //Create FetchedResultsController organizing by sections of first letter of name
    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"name.stringGroupByFirstInitial" cacheName:nil];
    //name.stringGroupByFirstInitial

    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

**didSelectRow**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
            {

                if (!self.detailViewController) {
                    self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController"    bundle:nil];
                }
                Whisky *whisky = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                [whisky setIsNew:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

                 self.detailViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
                 self.detailViewController.whisky = whisky;
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
            }
```

**NSFetchedResultsController Delegates**

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
    {
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    }

    - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
               atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
    {
        switch(type) {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                NSLog(@"didChangeSection - ChangeInsert");
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                NSLog(@"didChangeSection - ChangeDelete");
                break;
        }
    }

    - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
           atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
          newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
    {
        UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

        switch(type) {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                NSLog(@"didChangeObject - ChangeInsert");
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                NSLog(@"didChangeObject - ChangeDelete");
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
                NSLog(@"didChangeObject - ChangeUpdate");
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                NSLog(@"didChangeObject - ChangeMove");
                break;
        }
    }

    - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
    {
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
```

Comment: Show the code for the fetch requests and the cell selection.

Comment: @Wain let me know if you need anymore code.

Comment: Are your attributes actually BOOLs in the model?

Comment: Core Data converted them to NSNumbers from the datamodel

Comment: but yes in the .xcdatamodeld file they are set as Boolean

Comment: I guess the issue is that you're passing a string to the predicate and comparing it to a number. Try making the predicate category `id` type and passing a number instead of @"1".

Comment: That was it. Thanks @Wain I just didn't think it mattered once it was in the "predicateWithFormat" String. I thought that treated it as a string once it was passed in. Now on to my next issue. haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a string to the predicate, but comparing it to a number in the data model (the BOOL). The different data types do matter. Try making the `category` you're using to create the predicate an `id` type and passing a number instead of @"1".

Comment: If you would like to help me with my other issue it is right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645453/updating-uitableview-that-is-managed-by-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-has-1-ext