# Updating UITableView that is managed by NSFetchedResultsController and has 1 extra cell in the first section

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Master Detail Application -

I have a `UITableViewController` that is managed by an `NSFetchedResultsController` and its delegate methods. I also have one extra cell in the first section of the tableview that has a `UIWebView` in it that displays an embedded video. This cell is not part of the `NSFetchedResultsController`. I add it inside of an `IF` statement when `-tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called, that checks to see if it's the first section and first row. Everything works great for the most part. I can select a row and display it in the `DetailViewController`, I can delete items from the `tableView`, I can change the information in the `DetailViewController`and the `tableViewCell` labels update with out any problem.

**MY ISSUE**

The only time I have an issue with the way it is setup is, when I delete the last object from  the first section in the `tableView`.

**THE ERROR**

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught
>   from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section
>   after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in
>   that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows
>   inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus
>   or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved
>   in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

**CODE**

**numberOfRowsInSection**

This is where I check to see if the video is available and if the section is 0 return 1 extra row. else return the object count from the `NSFetchedResultsController`. I'm assuming this is where my issue is. However, I don't know how to fix it. Because I have it managed by the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods is there any thing I can do inside of the "type" in the switch statement?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0 && self.videoInfoReceived == YES) {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        return [secInfo numberOfObjects] + 1;
    } else {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        return [secInfo numberOfObjects];
    }

}
```

**NSFetchedResultsController Delegates**

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            NSLog(@"didChangeSection - ChangeInsert");
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            NSLog(@"didChangeSection - ChangeDelete");
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            NSLog(@"didChangeObject - ChangeInsert");
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            NSLog(@"didChangeObject - ChangeDelete");
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSLog(@"didChangeObject - ChangeUpdate");
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            NSLog(@"didChangeObject - ChangeMove");
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more conditional code to check if any index path you're sent is for the first (zero) section. If it is, the FRC is being given the 'wrong' row number because you have told the table view one row count and the FRC understands a different one.

Basically, everywhere you receive an index path **from the table view**, check the section, if it `== 0`, create a new index path with the same section and `row - 1` and use that to access the objects in the FRC.

Conversely, when you receive an index path **from the FRC** you need `row + 1` before you can use it to ask the table view to insert/delete/move.

Comment: I originally attempted this by checking if section == 0 and then created/updated the indexPath. Which originally wasn't working for me. But since I read your answer I decided to go back and try that again. It only worked if I checked if the section == 0 and if the [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] > 2. I don't know why, but it works. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In your question you state:

> when I delete the last object from the first section in the tableView

Which would lead me to expect the exception to state the following (emphasis added):

> CoreData: error: Serious application error. An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:. Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section **after the update (0)** must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section **before the update (1)**, plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section **(0 inserted, 1 deleted)** and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

Because the exception states that the row count is *increasing* from 2 to 3 without any rows being added, I think that your error is down in the model layer and not in the table view code. Your table view code looks great to me.

Comment: When I say delete the last object from the first section in the tableview I don't mean the very bottom object before the next section. I mean when there are multiple objects in the first section it works fine when I delete an object until I get to the last object besides the video webview cell.

Comment: I understood what you meant. Your fetched results controller doesn't know anything about your additional web view cell, so when you delete the last remaining row from a given section, the fetched results controller expects the row count to decrease from 1 to 0. The fact that the exception states that the row count is increasing from 2 to 3 tells me that the delete operation at the Core Data level is not architected correctly. Try commenting out your custom web view cell entirely and get deletions working properly with just a one-to-one table view cell to FRC item setup.

Comment: Once that's working, add in your extra cell by adjusting the row counts and indexPath.row values where appropriate to "translate" from the indexes of your table view with the indexes of the items in your fetched results.